# Use 2 welcome/finish page images in nsis

Tags: installation, nsis

I am using this code to change the `MUI_WELCOMEFINISH_BITMAP`, text and title of the welcome page.

```
Function MyWelcomeShowCallback
SendMessage $mui.WelcomePage.Text ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(MUI_TEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TEXT)$\n$\nVersion: foo.bar"
FunctionEnd

  !define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\bg2_2.bmp"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\License.txt"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

  !define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE "Title"
  !define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT  "Text"
  !define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW MyWelcomeShowCallback
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

I wanted to change the bitmap twice, once for welcome and once for finish page. Unfortunately `!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP $bmp` can only be used once. I know that it is possible to change bmp path in `Welcome.nsh`,  but I'd rather define everything in `.nsi` script. How can I set differenet images for welcome and finish page? In essence, how does one change the value if `!defined` was used to create it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no define you can set to use different images but you can overwrite the image before the page is displayed:

```
Function ForceWizard1
SetOverWrite on
File "/oname=$PLUGINSDIR\modern-wizard.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\llama.bmp"
SetOverWrite lastused
FunctionEnd
Function ForceWizard2
SetOverWrite on
File "/oname=$PLUGINSDIR\modern-wizard.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\orange-nsis.bmp"
SetOverWrite lastused
FunctionEnd

!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE ForceWizard1
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE ForceWizard2
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
```